# onclick change the name in drop down box

Tags: php

what i am trying to do is when i click on the submit button and try to get the value it is not displaying it properly . I am writing the code of 2 file down 1) enable.php 2) abc.php

File Name : enable.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showdetail(boxid){
                document.getElementById(boxid).style.display = "block";
            }

            function hidedetail(boxid){
                document.getElementById(boxid).style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="abc" method="post" action="abc.php">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="r" href="#" title="" alt="" onclick="showdetail('res'); hidedetail('comm');">bb</a></li>
                <li style="width: 1px;">|</li>
                <li style="width:85px;"><a id="r" href="#" title="" alt="" onclick="showdetail('comm'); hidedetail('res');">Cc</a></li>
                <li style="width: 2px;">|</li>  
            </ul>`
            <div id="res" style="display:none;">
                <select id="pr" name="pr" class="textarial12 textcolorgrey flot_left">
                    <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="comm" style="display:none;">
                <select id="pr" name="pr" class="textarial12 textcolorgrey flot_left">
                    <option value="Hi">Hi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

File Name :  abc.php

```
<?php
    $PropertyType=$_POST[pr];
    echo $PropertyType;
?>
```

Comment: Please correctly format the code

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` elements must be referenced as a string. Instead of:

```
$PropertyType=$_POST[pr];
```

please use:

```
$PropertyType=$_POST['pr'];
```

Comment: Thanks george for fast reply i am made the change but still problem is not resolved when you click on submit button the

Comment: @jim: Please update your question with more specific information: 1) What do you expect to see? 2) What action do you take? 3) What incorrect event occurs?